# Find duplicate values in list of dicts and summarize other relevand values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have list of dicts with product info. I need to summarize price field for the same products and to get the result in the same format.

I have:

```
data = [
    {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '200'},
    {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '300'},
    {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '400'},
    {'title': 'Samsung', 'price': '250'},
    {'title': 'Sony', 'price': '100'}
]
```

I need:

```
data = [
    {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '900'},
    {'title': 'Samsung', 'price': '250'},
    {'title': 'Sony', 'price': '100'}
]
```

Comment: Show us what you’ve tried that failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.groupby`:

```
[
    {'title': k, 'price': str(sum(int(i['price']) for i in g))}
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['title'])
]
```

- `for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['title'])` iterates over the key-group created by grouping `data` on `title`
- `{'title': k, 'price': str(sum(int(i['price']) for i in g))}` is a dict comprehension with the `price` value created by iterating over the groups and `sum`ming the `price`s

**Example:**

```
In [472]: data = [ 
     ...:     {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '200'}, 
     ...:     {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '300'}, 
     ...:     {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '400'}, 
     ...:     {'title': 'Samsung', 'price': '250'}, 
     ...:     {'title': 'Sony', 'price': '100'} 
     ...: ]                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [473]: [{'title': k, 'price': str(sum(int(i['price']) for i in g))} for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['title'])]                                                                       
Out[473]: 
[{'title': 'Apple', 'price': '900'},
 {'title': 'Samsung', 'price': '250'},
 {'title': 'Sony', 'price': '100'}]
```

---

If the input is not soorted, you need to sort it first based on the `title` key i.e:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['title'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my friend. You helped me a lot.@heemayl

Comment: @AlexCold Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
data = [
    {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '200'},
    {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '300'},
    {'title': 'Apple', 'price': '400'},
    {'title': 'Samsung', 'price': '250'},
    {'title': 'Sony', 'price': '100'}
]

price = {}

for row in data:
    if row['title'] not in price:
        price[row['title']] = 0
    price[row['title']] += int(row['price'])

data = []

for title in price:
    data.append({'title': title, 'price': str(price[title])})

print(data);
```